# cmake command syntax question

Tags: build-process, macros, compilation, cmake, portability

I require the syntax of a **CMAKE** macro that generates .cc and .h files from a tool like lex/yacc.

Could someone please show me the syntax for the following contrived example:

say I have a file y.cc that depends on x.cc and x.h, the two files mentioned are generated by tool z_tool from file x.z. What would the syntax for this be ?

For this example assume that y.cc will be turned into a static library, and as I am quite new to CMAKE the full CMakellist.txt for this contrived example would be very helpful.I'm looking for a portable solution as the tools I am using are available on windows as well as UNIX variants.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rather than give you the answer to a contrived example, here is the way you would generate an executable using [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex) and [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/)

```
find_package(BISON)
find_package(FLEX)

BISON_TARGET(MyParser parser.y ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parser.cc)
FLEX_TARGET(MyScanner lexer.l  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lexer.cc)
ADD_FLEX_BISON_DEPENDENCY(MyScanner MyParser)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
add_executable(Foo
  Foo.cc
  ${BISON_MyParser_OUTPUTS}
  ${FLEX_MyScanner_OUTPUTS})
target_link_libraries(Foo ${FLEX_LIBRARIES} ${BISON_LIBRARIES})
```

The CMake find packages for bison/flex are included in the default installation, so this is cross platform.

In general to create an output that will later be used as an input you can use the [add_custom_command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:add_custom_command) function. If you use an output from the custom command as an input to a library or executable, then CMake knows to run your custom command before compiling the sources for the library/executable target.

Comment: Nicely explained. The gist was indeed how to wire up the outputs and inputs :D

Comment: For posterity: also include something like `target_link_libraries(Foo ${FLEX_LIBRARIES} ${BISON_LIBRARIES}` in the cmake file.

Answer (score 1):

The following line has Typo

```
FLEX_TARGET(MyScanner lexer.l  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BIANRY_DIR}/lexer.cc)
```

**BIANRY** should be spelled as **BINARY**.

Note: CMake Documentation has this typo there as well. ( in 2.8.0, this is fixed in 2.8.10 documentation)..

Answer (score 1):

/* To make it work on my Mac with Lion.  I changed the files names to y.tab.c and lex.yy.c, which are the output files if you run lex lex.l and yacc -D yacc.y from command line.  See below.
*/

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project (LexYacc)

find_package(BISON)
find_package(FLEX)

BISON_TARGET(MyParser yacc.y ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/y.tab.c) 
FLEX_TARGET(MyScanner lex.l  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lex.yy.c)
ADD_FLEX_BISON_DEPENDENCY(MyScanner MyParser)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
add_executable(LexYacc
  ${BISON_MyParser_OUTPUTS}
  ${FLEX_MyScanner_OUTPUTS})
target_link_libraries(LexYacc ${FLEX_LIBRARIES} ${BISON_LIBRARIES})
```